# Decorate class method with another class method

Tags: python, class, methods, python-decorators

Say I have a class, and I want to decorate one of its methods with another. Like in the example:

```py
class Foobar:
    def foo(self, func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
             print(self + " is doing something")
             func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    @foo
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Foobar")
```

Of course, when I make an instance of `Foobar` and run `bar`, an exception will be raised because the function gets passed to `self` and there's nothing for `func`. But I can't just decorate `foo` with `staticmethod` because `self` is needed to run the `wrapped` function.

This is quite a dilemma. Can someone help?

Comment: That example fails during the _definition_ of Foobar because foo is called with only one argument: bar. You can't make an instance because the class definition never completes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. What I'm saying is, how can I pass the instance to `foo`?

Comment: Why do you need to? _wrapped_ gets called with self, because it replaces bar.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah.

Comment: See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `self` in the `foo()` method, but you can get it just by specifying it in the `wrapped()` function:

```py
class Foobar:
    def foo(func):
        print('foo is running')
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(str(self) + " is doing something")
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    @foo
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Foobar")
        print(self, args, kwargs)

print('Make Foobar')
f = Foobar()
f.bar(1, f=42)
print('Done')
```

Just to be clear, I've added some `print()` statements so you can see the order of operations:

```
foo is running
Make Foobar
<__main__.Foobar object at 0x03BE5210> is doing something
Foobar
<__main__.Foobar object at 0x03BE5210> (1,) {'f': 42}
Done
```

Comment: You really should just put the method outside the class at that point.